# How do you check for the actual error in SwiftMailer v4 when send() fails

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Is there a way to check for error when sending mail using SwiftMailer version 4?  I am not referring to getting a list of recipient emails that got rejected, and I am not talking about just knowing whether send() worked or not.

I am talking about knowing the actual error that took place during the sending process - such as not able to connect to STMP host, incorrect login, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Mailer - Can't send mail, and can't find error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366289/swift-mailer-cant-send-mail-and-cant-find-error-logs)

Answer (score -3):

Simply check the return code from SwiftMailer's send() or batchSend() commands for a non-zero result. If you get a non-zero result (i.e. TRUE), then it succeeded connecting and authenticating to your SMTP service.

From [the documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/send-method):

```
//Send the message
$numSent = $mailer->send($message);

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);

// Note that often that only the boolean equivalent of the
//  return value is of concern (zero indicates FALSE) 

if ($mailer->send($message))
{
  echo "Sent\n";
}
else
{
  echo "Failed\n";
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in knowing just whether the mail was sent successfully or not - I want to know WHAT error I am getting.  I've updated my question to be more clear.