# Laravel 5 SwiftMailer's Send: how to get error code

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am sending email similar to this: [Laravel 5: Sending Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378357/laravel-5-sending-email). This is how I do it:

```
$mail_status = Mail::send( 'emails.followup', $data, function( $message ) use ($data) {
             $message->to( $data['email'] )
            ->from( $data['email_from'], $data['email_name'] )
            ->subject( $data['subject'] );
        });

if($mail_status) {
    $ret_status = 'sent';
}
else
    $ret_status = 'sent_failed';
```

Now, if the `$ret_status` is 'sent_failed', I want to know what happened. How do I do it? How can I see the message from the mail server?

Here is my `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=thepassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

### Update

Looks like the approach above is Laravel 4. If you know how to get the error code using Laravel 5+, I can consider it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use try catch for that, also you mistaken that use `$email, $email_from, $email_name, $subject` without passing into function scope.

```
try{
    $mail_status = Mail::send( 'emails.followup', $data, function( $message ) use ($data, $email, $email_from, $email_name, $subject) {
                        $message->to( $email )
                        ->from( $email_from, $email_name )
                        ->subject( $subject );
                    });
    //If error from Mail::send
    if($mail_status->failures() > 0){
        //Fail for which email address...
        foreach(Mail::failures as $address) {
            print $address . ', ';
        }
        exit;
    }  
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    // Get error here
    print $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Added failure printing for email address to check email fail for which address.

Comment: @user1506104: Check this answer, Hope you get the solution from this

Comment: hello. this did not work. any other suggestion? @AddWeb

Comment: What does `print $e->getMessage();` for you?

Comment: There was no exception. $mail_status was 0 (false) though. It means, nothing was sent. Correct?

Comment: Added failure case now check

Comment: thats better. i'm actually more interested on the reason of the failure, not the list of failed emails. this will do for now. will wait for other answers. thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: The Mail::send() method doesn't return anything.
https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method_send

Comment: @user1506104 I think you should try to send mail with mandrill because mandrill store rejected and delivered mail and display reason for rejected mails and also reject which mail send to fake email address

Comment: @user1506104 Please check this link(https://blog.sarav.co/integrate-mandrill-mail-server-in-laravel/) for send mail through mandrill

Answer (score 5):

Checking `Mail::failures()` immediately after `Mail::send()` will return an array of failed email addresses you tried to send an email to.

However, as far as I know you cannot get the exact error on failure using Mail facade. For that, you need to set the debug true on your `.env` and check on Laravel log.

Comment: the log did not give me anything either. thanks for your suggestion. +1

Answer (score 3):

1. To get dev version of errors (on screen), set in your .env file `APP_DEBUG=true`
2. To get the exact message, do do the try catch, but catch `Swift_TransportException` https://stackoverflow.com/a/42221501/2119863
3. You may also, if needed, get the mailer instance via `app('mailer')` and do some research there.

here is a working example:

```
try{
    $mail_status = Mail::send( 'emails.followup', $data, function( $message ) use ($data) {
        $message->to( $data['email'] )
        ->from( $data['email_from'], $data['email_name'] )
        ->subject( $data['subject'] );
    });
}catch(\Swift_TransportException $e){
    dd($e, app('mailer'));
}
```

and the `dd()` result:

```
Swift_TransportException {#237 ▼
  #message: """
    Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required\r\n
    "
    """
  #code: 530
  #file: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a try catch block with a `Swift_TransportException` exception in your catch and then call `getCode()` on that exception.

Regardless of your `.env` settings you can always call `getCode()` on the exception passed to the catch callback. This returns the code of your exception.

I recommend using `\Swift_TransportException` inside your catch for the reason that Laravel utilises Symfony's Swift Mailer and these are the type of exceptions it throws; however, it does extend `Exception` at a deeper level, so you can also use `\Exception`.

Here's an example:

```
try {     
    insert mail code here ...           
} 
catch(\Swift_TransportException $e) { // alternatively use \Exception
    // dump error
    dd($e->getCode());
}
```

The above block will dump the `Swift_TransportException` code passed to its constructor. If you want the full error message you can also run `getMessage()`.

You can find the complete documentation for the `Exception` class and subsequent `Swift_TransportException` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) for any other methods you might want to use.

---

Edit: This is supported in Laravel 4 and above (including 5+ as requested.).