# Can't send mail with Gmail

Tags: php, symfony, gmail, wamp, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send an email when a user is subscribing in my web site.
To save me time ... I'm using [Swift_Mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html) with [Symfony](https://symfony.com/).

First, I tried to send a mail with the console :

```
php .\bin\console swiftmailer:email:send
```

And that's working, the mail was sent and the client received it.

So now I said to myself, I will be able to send emails with the code.
That's my Controller code :

```
public function register(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    // Here saving new user in the database 

    $this->sendMail($user->getEMail(), $mailer);

    $content = $this->renderView("register.html.twig");
    return new Response($content);
}

private function sendMail($email, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom(['my.email@gmail.com' => "my name"])
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setBody('Here is the message itself');

    $mailer->send($message);
}
```

And That's my .env file :

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://my.email@gmail.com:myPasswordHere@localhost
```

When I'm trying to send the mail, no error, I tried [this StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366289/swift-mailer-cant-send-mail-and-cant-find-error-logs), but no problem, echo "Successfull", but nothing in the Gmail send box and nothing my client email box.

Can you please help me to ... **save me time** ^^

------------------------------------------------------------- EDIT 1 ------------------------------------------------------------

I never edited the `config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml` file, that's it's content :

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

------------------------------------------------------------- EDIT 2 ------------------------------------------------------------

I also tryed to make a new transporter with this code :

```
$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465))
        ->setUsername('my.email@gmail.com')
        ->setPassword('myPasswordHere');
$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
```

And that's the error I get : `Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Unknown host. #0]`

------------------------------------------------------------- EDIT 3 ------------------------------------------------------------

I've got a `swiftmailer.yaml` fil in the `config/packages/dev` folder and that's it's default content :

```
# See https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/dev_environment.html
swiftmailer:
    # send all emails to a specific address
    #delivery_addresses: ['me@example.com']
```

I tried to put the same content as in the `config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml`, but no result.

Comment: Have you configure swiftmailer ? If not, those lines in your yaml config files can help : `swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }`

Comment: Thx @titili, look at my edit plz :)

Comment: And in your dev config directory ? Do you have a swiftmailer.yaml file ? In my symfony project, I use it to redirect all the emails to a specific adress and have no problems. `swiftmailer:
    delivery_addresses: ['dev@example.com']`

Comment: Sorry for this noob question but, where is the "dev config" repository plz ? :P

Comment: Sorry, as you mention a swiftmailer file, I deduct you were using Symfony 4 in which config files are in `config/packages` directory. It contains `dev`, `prod`, `test` directories in which you can configure your application according to your environment.

Comment: I'm using the Symfony 4 version, but I was talking about the config/package/swiftmailer.yaml file. Do I have to copy paste the cotent to the dev, prod and test content ?

Comment: No, configuration in `config/packages` is common to each environment. I was guessing that dev environment maybe needs more configuration. But, if you don't have a `swiftmailer.yaml` in dev directory; this is probably not the problem.

Comment: Please @titili have a look at my "Edit 3"

Comment: Well, I suppose the problem may come from your `MAILER_URL`. Indeed, this environment variable is a shortcut for the code you described in your second edit and it seems that it does not work. You can try adding those lines in `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml` : `web_profiler:
    intercept_redirects: true` in order to see if you can get more informations about the problem.

Comment: Maybe take a look at your gmail account configuration also ! [Symfony - Gmail](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html#using-gmail-to-send-emails)

Comment: My Gmail Account seems good, as I said, can send mail with the console.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see something like this in your code:

```
    // Create the Transport
    $transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('mail hoster etc', port))
        ->setUsername('your email')
        ->setPassword('your password');
    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
```

Maybe it's a reason why your mails isn't sent.

Comment: What makes you think that one should have such code? If sending mail works from the console, without having written such code, the problem might not be the same